# How do I increase the memory limit of firebase scheduled functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions) mentions using `.runWith({memory: "1GB"})`, but how do I use this option with a scheduled function like this:

```
functions.pubsub.schedule('every 10 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {
    console.log("Do something");
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do as follows:

```
functions.runWith({memory: "1GB"}).pubsub.schedule('every 10 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {
    console.log("Do something");
    // Don't forget to return a Promise if necessary!! 
    // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As per now, if you are using Firebase then native way is to use the **onSchedule** which takes two parameters! **options** and **handler**

```
const { onSchedule } = require("firebase-functions/v2/scheduler");

exports.theScheduledFunction = onSchedule(
  {
    schedule: "* */5 * * *", // Cron Syntax
    memory: "512MiB", // Allocate 512 MiB memory
    timeoutSeconds: 300, // Set a timeout of 300 seconds
  },
  async (event) => {
    // Place your code here
  }
);
```

**To Deploy with firebase cli**  `firebase deploy --only functions:theScheduledFunction`